# Failed to init WebLogic - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, server, weblogic, classnotfoundexception, wlst

When I checked in WLS-CAT I found that class was loaded by [_wl_cls_gen.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXox0.png)

But, when I try to start WebLogic this error is happened:

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxq8v.png)

```
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.app.component.TaskSchedulerFactory

            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)

            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)

            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)

            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)

            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)

            at br.com.caelum.vraptor.scan.DynamicWebAppBootstrap.configure(DynamicWebAppBootstrap.java:45)

            at br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.guice.GuiceProvider$2.configure(GuiceProvider.java:123)

            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)

            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)

            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:92)

            at com.google.inject.util.Modules$RealOverriddenModuleBuilder$1.configure(Modules.java:172)

            at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)

            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)

            at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)

            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)

            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)

            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)

            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:83)

            at br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.guice.GuiceProvider.start(GuiceProvider.java:97)

            at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.init(VRaptor.java:119)

            at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.init(VRaptor.java:114)

            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:343)

            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)

            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)

            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.loadFilter(FilterManager.java:96)

            at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.preloadFilters(FilterManager.java:57)

            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)

            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3155)

            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)

            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:487)

            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)

            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)

            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)

            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:201)

            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:249)

            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)

            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)

            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)

            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:28)

            at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:672)

            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)

            at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)

            at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)

            at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)

            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)

            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)

            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)

            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)

            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)

            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)

            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)

            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)

            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:164)

            at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)

            at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)

            at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)

            at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)

            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)

            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

It seems as if the ChangeAwareClassLoader class wasn't called.

The file weblogic.xml have config:

```
<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
```

Someone can help me? 
Thanks

Comment: paste the stack trace here

Comment: @sidgate, I aprecciate your attention. I updated the code and improved the question.